# Is there a way to play with functions attributes in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, attributes

I am currently building a monitoring system for our scripts and I thought that the ideal situation would be to have a function that takes the function name, date, and input (in case of starting) and log it our DB then doing the same when the function ends.

I have come across some solutions for this like metaclasses and decorators like `@function_name` but I came up with a curious idea.

The idea is to create a class which takes in a class full of methods and implements a logging function into every method in that class.

Starting class ->

```py
class Bar:
    def barmethod(self):
        return "Hello world"
```

Class that modifies class methods ->

````py
class Foo(object):
     def __init__(self, cls):
         for method in cls:
             method.__init__ = self.log_function

     def log_function(self):
         #get name of function that executes this
         #log into db

```python
foo class would basically implement that log function in the __init__ attribute of that cls method.
````

Execution ->

```py
foo = Foo(Bar()) #all methods inside Foo now have a modified __init__ so when they are called they will execute log_function with their name as argument
```

Is this doable or are function inner attributes unmodifiable? Should I go back to metaclasses or decorators?

Also I know the argument (function name) are not defined for log_function but I have no idea how or where to get them

The full process

```py
Bar has method -> Foo changes that method to execute a function when called -> Call Foo method -> Foo method calls log_function -> Foo continues with its initial purpose, return hello world -> end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a Rube Goldberg contraption to me. Instead of trying to reinvent the wheel, just use the canonical pythonic solutions (function decorators level to add the logging and eventually class decorators or metaclass to automagicall apply the function decorators to all methods). Also, logging to database is usually a very bad idea - it adds some serious overhead and if anything goes wrong with the database, your ALL application is broken. Better to use the stlib's `logging` module and configure it at the app level so you can have more fine-grained control on what is logged, how and where.

Comment: Alright, thanks, I will go back to logging and decorators which was my first idea. Do you know if the attributes of functions can be modified though? Or are they read-only?

Comment: Did you try by yourself ? That's quite easy you know... But well, yes, you can _usually_ add / remove / replace functions attributes, just like with (and with the same restrictions as) any other object. Whether it's a good idea is another debate... Now in your case it wouldn't work for various reasons, the first one being that magic methods are never looked up on instances, only on the class.

Comment: Thanks @brunodesthuilliers

Comment: You're welcome ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I myself was causing an error due to propagation of the metaclass into all the other classes. All classes looked like this:

```py
class Foo(Apis, metaclass=Monitor)
```

Due to all classes inheriting Monitor the error was caused, I did not know metaclasses propagate with inheritance, since all my classes Inherit directly or indirectly from Apis, I only had to delete `metaclass=Monitor` from all my classes except Apis